# Linking a single frame to an ActionScript class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I am trying to have a specific actionscript class run on one of the frames I have in my flash program. I don't want to link the whole thing to the class as it causes errors and is just plain wrong.

What I mean by this is in the publish settings in Flash professional I want to link an actionscript class, but only for one frame.

Anybody know how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why would you need this? By "linking a frame", do you mean grouping everything on the frame into a symbol and linking that to a Class? As far as i know frames are special properties unique to the MovieClip Class, and cannot be manipulated like other DisplayObjects.

Comment: You can also add code to frames by right clicking on them and using the actions panel.

Comment: @MartonPallagi this makes more sense than what I was trying to do. So to clarify, you are suggesting I make another MovieClip symbol with the content I wish and link the actionscript to that instead?

Comment: Yes, if you wish to access the objects on that specific frame via a class, you should put the whole thing in a movieclip (and then link said movieclip in the library to your class). All the instances will be available for that class. If you just need some generic code to execute on said frame, it's easier to use the actions panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an association between your frames and some classes, use a switch:

```
switch( currentFrame )
{
   case 1 :
   //use this class;
   break;

case 2 :
   //use this class;
   break;

default :
   //this frame doesn't have a class associated to it.
}
```